# Draw an arc given two points and a radius

Tags: geometry, html5-canvas

Draw an arc given two points and a radius.

How can I understand the answer given here?

[Draw an Arc from a start point, end point and a radius](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36866291/draw-an-arc-from-a-start-point-end-point-and-a-radius)

https://stackoverflow.com/a/36872927/261439

Answer (score 1):

Let start point is `S`, end point is `E`

Center `C` lies at middle perpendicular to `SE` segment, so we should find vectors:

```
se = (E.x - S.x, E.y - S.y)
perp = (-se.y, se.x) = (S.y - E.y, E.x - S.x)
perp_normalized = perp / Len(perp)
L = Len(perp) = sqrt((S.y - E.y)^2+(S.x - E.x)^2)
perp_normalized = (S.y - E.y)/L, (E.x - S.x)/L
```

and middle point of `SE` segment

```
M = ((E.x + S.x)/2, (E.y + S.y)/2)
```

Distance from `M` to circle center is

```
D = sqrt(R^2-L^2/4)
```

Now we can express circle  center `C` coordinates using parametric equation, there are two possible variants:

```
C = M +/- perp_normalized*D

C1.x = M.x + perp_normalized.x * D
C1.y = M.y + perp_normalized.y * D

C2.x = M.x - perp_normalized.x * D
C2.y = M.y - perp_normalized.y * D
```

Having center, you can define parameters needed for drawing of arc in your framework

Answer (score 0):

C is the midpoint of DE, so AB and DE are perpendicular (**midpoint theorem**)

AC=sqrt(AD^2-CD^2) (**Pythagoras theorem**)

DE=sqrt(AD^2-CD^2) (**Pythagoras theorem**)

Triangle ACF and EDG are **similar triangle**s, scaled by ratio AC:DE=AF:EG=CF:DG

DG and EG are known. AC and DE are given above. Then we get CF and AF. (And it can be proven that dX(G->D) and dY(C->F) same sign; dX(E->G) and dY(F->A) revsrse sign.)

Therefore we get the center of circle.

And we can get points on the arc by rotating D around A. ([rotation formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_(mathematics)#Two_dimensions))

[image]